# Syntax error when inserting ID, timestamp and string into Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, vbscript

Can someone kindly tell me why this code throws a syntax error? :

```
commText = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (" & (recordsQty + 1) & "," & currentUserID & ",#" & Now & "#, '" & messageText & "')"
conn.Open connStr
conn.Execute commText
conn.Close()
```

The table I'm inserting to is as follows:

```
ID Number PK
userID Number FK
messageDate Date/Time
messageText Text
```

And, finally, the code throws this error:

```
Script error detected at line 20.
Source line: conn.execute commText
Description: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you everyone, it is working now. I don't know what was throwing the error - hashtags go through as well as single quotes, I'm guessing that the fields have to be specified explicitly...

Comment: General advice: do **not** build SQL queries by string concatenation. **Ever.** Use [parametrized queries](http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilcar/archive/2008/05/21/sql-injection-mitigation-using-parameterized-queries.aspx) (AKA prepared statements) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your ID field is set to autoincrement, you don't need to specify it in the where clause.

```
commText = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (" & currentUserID & ",#" & Now & "#, '" & messageText & "')"
```

Also you'll need to ensure currentUserID  exists in the foreign key's table

Comment: `commText = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (" & currentUserID & ",#" & Now & "#, '" & messageText & "')" ` will fail you have to list columns explicitly.

Comment: @LIUFA - It will fail if the primary key is NOT set to auto increment. Otherwise it should work fine in access because the ID field is generated automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
commText = "INSERT INTO Messages (userID, messageDate, messageText) " & _
           "VALUES (" & currentUserID & ", #" & Now & "#, '" & messageText & "')"
```

Or if your primary key is not auto increment:

```
commText = "INSERT INTO Messages (ID, userID, messageDate, messageText) " & _
           "VALUES (" & (recordsQty + 1) & ", "  & currentUserID & ", #" & Now & "#, '" & messageText & "')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Swagata is correct you do not need to specify the auto-column however you need to specify columns explicitly, if they do not match table that you are inserting into structure exactly.

```
commText = "INSERT INTO Messages (UserId, messageDate, messageText  ) VALUES (" & currentUserID & ",#" & Now & "#, '" & messageText & "')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your hashtags with single quote.

```
commText = "INSERT INTO Messages VALUES (" & (recordsQty + 1) & "," & currentUserID & ",'" & Now & "', '" & messageText & "')"
```